# OutOfMemory Exception on 8-bit PNG

Tags: c#, wpf, out-of-memory, png, bitmapimage

Visual Studio 2015 debug (x86) throws `OutOfMemory` exception on a **8-bit-PNG**, but not on a **32-bit-PNG**. If I change debug to (any CPU), then the program runs both **8-bit** and **32-bit** image just fine. Both 8-bit and original 32-bit PNG are the same image, where I used Photoshop to convert the original 32-bit to 8-bit PNG. Even when OutOfMemory is thrown, Task Manager does not reflect any memory issue (both below 100MB).

What makes it even more strange is, if I first run (i.e. adding to a StackPanel) the 32-bit PNG before I did to an 8-bit PNG, then the program runs just fine without OutOfMemory exception, which only gets thrown if the it the 8-bit PNG is first image to be added to the StackPanel.

This seemingly make no sense?

```
Image _img = new Image();
BitmapImage _bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_path, UriKind.Absolute));
_img.Source = _bi;
stackPanel.Children.Add(_img)
```

Comment: It could be that the 8bit image is corrupt. Have you tried to recreate/resave it, maybe with a different image program?

Comment: What is the size (dimensions)of your image. The compressed size is not a big help. The PNG compression is quite good on specific images and the problem can be in image dimensions. Displayed images are uncompressed.

Comment: That 8-bit image can be opened in other program, and there are multiple 8-bit images that could not be all corrupted, and I literally tried individually. If it is corrupted, that second question would also throw the same exception, but it didn't That was the intriguing part.

Comment: Image size is 1200x800 for both 32-bit (~450kb) and 8-bit image (~150kb).

Comment: Won't hurt if you can provide reproducable example (full xaml\C# code + image(s) in question).

Comment: For 8bit image, rather than using Photoshop, you could use another image software to test it.

Comment: Do you also get the exception when you set `_bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat`? Or with `_img.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(_path, UriKind.Absolute))`? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your 8-bit PNG image probably has **incorrect `DPI` metadata**. At some point, the WPF renderer tries to scale your image. Due to wrong `DPI` you then get a crazy large bitmap which in this case is too large for a 32-bit application.

If the memory usage is indeed stable, I guess the image scaling method throws the `OutOfMemoryException` before actually allocating the bitmap data. E.g.:

```
if (calculatedBitmapSize > int.MaxValue)
    throw new OutOfMemoryException();
```